# Set result message in AJAX request for newsletter subscription form (Shopware 6)

Tags: ajax, shopware

I wrote a Shopware 6 plugin, which offers a newsletter subscription form in my footer area. Newsletter subscriptions are managed in a third party system, connected via Soap API. This API is working fine. Only I do not know how to provide a error/success message in my Shopware plugin, and how to display this to the user. The form is submitted via Ajax, and always shows a success message. I want to display an error if the email address is already subscribed.

Here's the form twig template, which already does a basic syntax validation:

```
<form action="{{ path('frontend.form.newsletter.register.handle') }}"
      method="post"
      id="newsletter-subscribe-form"
      data-form-csrf-handler="true"
      data-form-validation="true"
      data-form-ajax-submit="true">
    {{ sw_csrf('frontend.form.newsletter.register.handle') }}
    {% set formViolations = app.request.get('errors') %}
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="subscribe"/>
    <input type="submit" class="submit--hidden d-none">
    <div class="form-content">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group input-group col-md-8">
                <input name="email"
                       type="email"
                       id="footerNewsletterMail"
                       placeholder="{{ "account.personalMailPlaceholder"|trans }}{{ "general.required"|trans }}"
                       required="required"
                       value="{{ data.get('email') }}"
                       class="form-control{% if formViolations.getViolations('/email') %} is-invalid{% endif %}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group input-group col-md-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
                    Subscribe now!
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My `src/Resources/app/storefront/src/main.js` is listening to the form's `onAfterAjaxSubmit` and displays a nice modal dialog with the returned messages:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var subscribeForm = document.querySelector('#newsletter-subscribe-form');
    var instance = PluginManager.getPluginInstanceFromElement(subscribeForm, 'FormAjaxSubmit');
    instance.$emitter.subscribe('onAfterAjaxSubmit', function(response) {
        $dialog = $('#newsletter-thanks-dialog');
        responseDetails = JSON.parse(response.detail.response);
        var modalContents = '';
        responseDetails.forEach(function(detail) {
            modalContents += '<p>'+detail.alert+'</p>';
        });
        $dialog.find('.modal-body').html(modalContents);
        $dialog.modal('show');
    });
});
```

Now what my event subscriber in `src/Subscriber/DoRegisterNewsletter.php` does looks like this, and this is where I want to return some error message, e.g. when the given email address is already subscribed in the external newsletter system:

```php
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            NewsletterRegisterEvent::class => 'onRegisterMyNewsletter',
        ];
    }

    public function onRegisterMyNewsletter(NewsletterRegisterEvent $event)
    {
        // Simplified code:
        /** @var bool $isRegistered */
        $isRegistered = $this->checkIfEmailIsRegistered($event->getNewsletterRecipient()->getEmail());
        if($isRegistered) {
            // Now how to set a response for the current Ajax request?
        }
        else {
            $this->goAndSubscribeMe($event->getNewsletterRecipient()->getEmail());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that event subscriber is called in `FormController->handleSubscribe()`, but its *result* is not used for anything. So the subscription to that event does more work like a "*hello, I was just called, just for your info*".

Alternatively to subscribing an event, one could decorate a service, like described in the [Shopware docs](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/decorating-a-service) and in the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html). This offers more control, like modifying the result of a method.